# NullPointer Exception ao inserir dados em uma chave Estrageira

Tags: java, postgresql, nullpointerexception

Estou enfrentando alguns problemas com a inserção de dados na minha tabela clientes. Especificamente com as chaves estrangeiras `fk_telefone_fisico` e `fk_telefone_juridico`.

Quando vou cadastrar o usuário ee me dá um `NullPointerException`, mas não sei de onde vem esse erro, já que não consigo identificar o ponteiro nulo. Segue o Código do DAO:

```
public void Salvar (ClienteFisico cf, TelefoneFisico t, EnderecoFisico end) throws Exception{

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
    PreparedStatement ps3 = null;

    if (cf == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Erro: Cliente não pode ser nulo!");
    }

    try {

        String sql2 ="insert into tbl_telefone_fisico (telefone_fixo_fisico, celular1_fisico, celular2_fisico, flag_ativo) values (?,?,?,1)";
        ps2 = this.con.prepareStatement(sql2, ps2.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        String sql3 = "insert into tbl_endereco_fisico (cidade_fisico, cep_fisico, estado_fisico, bairro_fisico, rua_fisico, numero_fisico, flag_ativo) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,1)";
        ps3 = this.con.prepareStatement(sql3, ps3.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        String sql = "insert into tbl_clientefisico(nome_cliente, sobrenome_cliente, cpf, rg, email,fk_telefone_fisico, fk_endereco_fisico, flag_ativo) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1)";
        ps = this.con.prepareStatement(sql, ps.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);


        ps2.setString(1, t.getTelefoneFixo());
        ps2.setString(2, t.getCelular1());
        ps2.setString(3, t.getCelular2());


        ResultSet rs2 = ps2.getGeneratedKeys();
        while(rs2.next()){

        int idTelGerado = rs2.getInt(1);
        t.setIdTelefone(idTelGerado);
        }


        ps3.setString(1, end.getCidade());
        ps3.setString(2, end.getCep());
        ps3.setString(3, end.getEstado());
        ps3.setString(4, end.getBairro());
        ps3.setString(5, end.getRua());
        ps3.setString(6, end.getNumero());


        ResultSet rs3 = ps3.getGeneratedKeys();
        while(rs3.next()){

        int idEndGerado = rs3.getInt(1);
        end.setIdEndereco(idEndGerado);
        }


        ps.setString(1, cf.getSobrenomeCliente());
        ps.setString(2, cf.getCpfCliente());
        ps.setString(3, cf.getRgCliente());
        ps.setString(4, cf.getEmailCliente());
        ps.setInt(5, cf.getTelefoneCliente().getIdTelefone());
        ps.setInt(6, cf.getEndereçoCliente().getIdEndereco());


        ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        while (rs.next()){
        int idPessoaGerado = rs.getInt(1);
        cf.setIdCliente(idPessoaGerado);
        }


        ps2.executeUpdate();
        ps3.executeUpdate();
        ps.executeUpdate();

        ps2.close();
        ps3.close();
        ps.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Erro ao inserir os dados: " + e.toString());
    }
    finally{
        ConnectionFactory.CloseConnection(con, ps);
    }
```

Como podem ver, parece tudo certo, mas quando clico em cadastrar(JButton) ele me dá um NullPointer. Segue o código do Botão Cadastrar:

```
 BotaoCadastrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {

            if(ClienteFisico == true)
            {

            EnderecoFisico end = new EnderecoFisico();
            TelefoneFisico tel = new TelefoneFisico();
            ClienteFisico cf = new ClienteFisico();


            tel.setCelular1(TxtCelular1.getText());
            tel.setCelular2(TxtCelular2.getText());
            end.setCidade(TxtCidadeCliente.getText());
            end.setCep(TxtCepCliente.getText());
            end.setBairro(TxtBairroCliente.getText());
            end.setEstado(TxtEstadoCliente.getText());
            end.setRua(TxtClientesRua.getText());
            end.setNumero(TxtNumCliente.getText());
            cf.setNomeCliente(TxtNomeCliente.getText());
            cf.setSobrenomeCliente(TxtSobreomeCliente.getText());
            cf.setCpfCliente(TxtCpfCnpjCliente.getText());
            cf.setRgCliente(TxtRgIeCliente.getText());
            cf.setEmailCliente(TxtEmailCliente.getText());
            tel.setTelefoneFixo(TxtTelFixo.getText());


            try{
                if(cfcont.Cadastrar(cf,tel,end))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!", "FUNCIONOU!", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){

                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao cadastrar o Cliente " + ex.toString(), "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }
        }
            else if (ClienteFisico == false)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ainda não é possível cadastar cliente Jurídico", "Ops!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Cade a pilha de erros? Edite a pergunta e adicione essa pilha de erros.

Comment: Olá e obrigado por responder, o problema foi resolvido. E só pra informar, a pilha de erros não aparecia, o erro aparecia em um JOptionPane, que mostrava esse NullPointer. no Output mostrava "montado com sucesso". Agradeço pela atenção e bom dia!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Fim das contas, resolvi o problema! Usamos sequências no BD para o próprio banco fazer o serviço pra nós. Segue o código Atualizado:

```
public void Salvar (ClienteFisico cf, TelefoneFisico t, EnderecoFisico end) throws Exception{

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
    PreparedStatement ps3 = null;

    if (cf == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Erro: Cliente não pode ser nulo!");
    }

    try {

        String sql2 ="insert into tbl_telefone_fisico (id_telefone, telefone_fixo_fisico, celular1_fisico, celular2_fisico, flag_ativo)"
                + " values (NEXTVAL('sequencia_telefone_fisico'), ?, ?, ?, 1)";
        ps2 = this.con.prepareStatement(sql2);

        String sql3 = "insert into tbl_endereco_fisico (id_endereco, cidade_fisico, cep_fisico, estado_fisico, bairro_fisico, rua_fisico, numero_fisico, flag_ativo)"
                + " values (NEXTVAL('sequencia_endereco_fisico'), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1)";
        ps3 = this.con.prepareStatement(sql3);

       String sql = "insert into tbl_clientefisico(id_cliente_fisico, nome_cliente, sobrenome_cliente, cpf, rg, email,fk_telefone_fisico, fk_endereco_fisico, flag_ativo)"
                + " values (NEXTVAL('sequencia_cliente_fisico'), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRVAL('sequencia_telefone_fisico'), CURRVAL('sequencia_endereco_fisico'), 1)";
        ps = this.con.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps2.setString(1, t.getTelefoneFixo());
        ps2.setString(2, t.getCelular1());
        ps2.setString(3, t.getCelular2());





        ps3.setString(1, end.getCidade());
        ps3.setString(2, end.getCep());
        ps3.setString(3, end.getEstado());
        ps3.setString(4, end.getBairro());
        ps3.setString(5, end.getRua());
        ps3.setString(6, end.getNumero());


        ps.setString(1, cf.getNomeCliente());
        ps.setString(2, cf.getSobrenomeCliente());
        ps.setString(3, cf.getCpfCliente());
        ps.setString(4, cf.getRgCliente());
        ps.setString(5, cf.getEmailCliente());




        ps2.executeUpdate();
        ps3.executeUpdate();
        ps.executeUpdate();

        ps2.close();
        ps3.close();
        ps.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Erro ao inserir os dados: " + e.toString());
    }
    finally{
        ConnectionFactory.CloseConnection(con, ps);
    }



}
```

Não Foram necessárias alterações no botão em si, então não acho necessário postar o código do botão novamente.